# How to run tikz in xaringan?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I am a newbie of xaringan and trying to draw some pictures using **tikz** package.
I was wondering how to run **tikz** in **xaringan** slides.

My codes are:

````
---
title: "Econ"
subtitle: "Lecture 1"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "College"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    
---

```{r,engine='tikz'}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,379); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 379

%Rounded Rect [id:dp1857476422681199] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 241; green, 192; blue, 192 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (228,123) .. controls (228,114.16) and (235.16,107) .. (244,107) -- (343,107) .. controls (351.84,107) and (359,114.16) .. (359,123) -- (359,171) .. controls (359,179.84) and (351.84,187) .. (343,187) -- (244,187) .. controls (235.16,187) and (228,179.84) .. (228,171) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp08440493370073976] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 226; green, 233; blue, 201 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (415,115) -- (525,115) -- (525,179) -- (415,179) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Single Corner Rect [id:dp01343887372328001] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.05 ] (64,129.52) .. controls (64,122.27) and (69.87,116.4) .. (77.12,116.4) -- (170,116.4) -- (170,182) -- (64,182) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9440635149995973] 
\draw    (171,144) -- (218,144) ;
\draw [shift={(221,144)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7316344569835018] 
\draw    (361,145) -- (405,145) ;
\draw [shift={(408,145)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Curve Lines [id:da512763546270846] 
\draw    (415,179) .. controls (380.35,241.37) and (217.31,242.97) .. (171.36,183.81) ;
\draw [shift={(170,182)}, rotate = 54.2] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
\draw   (280.56,238.98) -- (311.32,217.88)(282.27,217.6) -- (309.61,239.25) ;

% Text Node
\draw (420,125) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{y} }}\\{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textit{variables}}};
% Text Node
\draw (75,129) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{x}}}\\{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textit{variables}}};
% Text Node
\draw (271,138.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$function$};


\end{tikzpicture}

```
````

My code generates the following error with the same weird outcome, which is just the copy of my codes.

[image]

`Error in if (to_svg) tinytex::latexmk(texf, "latex") else tinytex::latexmk(texf) :  argument is of length zero`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. This works fine in my case.

Comment: It is so weird. With the same code, the same error keeps occurring. It just reproduces whole codes. Please see above for the updated version. Thanks.

Comment: No it does not work. Seems that it's getting worse. Even without tikz part, it still keeps running without stopping or generating anything. some packages are conflicting with each other. But I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: After installing `tinytex` package and then tinytex **latex distribution**, first-time use may take a while since it needs to install some tex package at first if needed.

Comment: After trying with different output option (pdf, html...), I realize that ```{r chunk} causes all troubles with html output including xaringan. I will post this issue separately shortly and let you know. Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

You are having the error `Error in if (to_svg) tinytex::latexmk(texf, "latex") else tinytex::latexmk(texf) :  argument is of length zero`, due to most probably, you don't have the `{tinytex}` package installed. **Because `tikz` engine requires the `{tinytex}` package to compile TikZ graphics to other foramts (e.g., svg or png).**

So try installing the `{tinytex}` package at first. [See here](https://yihui.org/tinytex/#for-r-users) how to do that.

Then also add the `echo=FALSE` in chunk option.

Comment: This time, the program keeps running without stopping. Seems never stop.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with my codes. With echo = FALSE option, it is still running without generating any error or result, which is so weird.

Comment: Now it stops with the same result as before.

Comment: Sure, give me a second. I will let you know rightaway.

Comment: Yes, it works perfect, but the code above was much simplified version. When I run your code with my original codes, nothing changes. So I guess that my original codes has a serious error or mistakes, which I still can't figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Sorry, please see my revised post with YAML section above one more time.

Comment: Same here. It works perfect. Then it is conflicting with some elements in other slides? Sigh.... Above codes are just one page from all other pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247048/discussion-between-shafee-and-joe).